# 'method' object is not iterable when trying to add data to database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to insert data into a table, but the error 'method' object is not iterable' is displayed in the console. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute(
        insert(text('users')).values(
        {"fio": name, "datar": '11.08.1984', "id_role": randint(1, 2)}
        ))
        conn.commit()
```

Here are the errors that are thrown:

```
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\main.py", line 41, in registration
conn.execute(
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1011, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1115, in _execute_clauseelement
compiled_sql = elem.compile(
File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 481, in compile
return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 487, in _compiler
return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 592, in __init__
Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 322, in __init__
self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 352, in process
return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 96, in _compiler_dispatch
return meth(self, **kw)
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 2467, in visit_insert
crud_params = crud._setup_crud_params(
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\crud.py", line 64, in _setup_crud_params
return _get_crud_params(compiler, stmt, **kw)
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\crud.py", line 158, in _get_crud_params
_scan_cols(
File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\crud.py", line 316, in _scan_cols
for c in cols:
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the code. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `for c in cols:` is where the issue is, please include more code so we can help.

Comment: Try with: `insert(text('users'),  ["fio", "datar","id_role"]  ).values( {"fio": name, "datar": '11.08.1984', "id_role": randint(1, 2)} )` that's because you didn't declare the users table so you should indicate the matching cols if you refer the table with it's name with a string

Comment: I tried! Now it gives the following error:   File "C:\Users\gibso\PycharmProjects\test_task\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\dml.py", line 50, in process_single
    return dict((c.key, pval) for c, pval in zip(self.table.c, p))
AttributeError: 'TextClause' object has no attribute 'c'

Comment: However, I don't have this line in my code.